# Migration websites to Azure platform

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services, azure-virtual-machine

We have several website hosted on a dedicated server with following configuration

- Windows OS based dedicated server
- MS SQL SERVER Windows 2012 for database
- IIS 7.5+
- and other software to managing website such as plesk
- We have developed websites in asp.net web-form with framework 4.0 or 4.5 (about 10 website)
- We also have few asp.net MVC based website with framework 4.5 (about 5 websites)
- We use InProc default session state for sessions
- beside this we have other software installed for security etc.
- we also have mobile application api running same server and same application is use to send push notification to OS & Android devices

Now i have few question regarding migration to Azure enviroment.

**First**, my big concerns are session state, i want to migrate to Azure without making any changes to code except changes to web.config is this possible?

**Second** we use MS SQL SERVER 2012 as database and on azure we have to use Azure SQL Database which i believe is not same as MS SQL SERVER, Can i use Azure SQL Database or i should still to MS SQL SERVER as i have application running on this and migrating to Azure database may create problems?

**Third**, let us say i choose web+Mobile--> App Service Standard Package (which comes with upto 10 instance) what are these instance? and will individual session always connect to same instance?

**Forth**: I have about 20 database one of them is about 6GB & other database are about 200MB-700MB which service should i use for database in case i use Azure SQL Database

- Single Database or Elastic?
- Can i create multiple database under elastic mode?
- Let us say if i choose "100 eDTUs: 10 GB included storage per pool, 200 DBs per pool, $0.20/hour" will i have total of 10GB space for all
  database in elastic pool and what is per pool and how many pools will
  i get in this option.

or MS SQL SERVER on Virtual Machine is better option as i can run SQL Server based session

**Fifth**: Disk Space, let us say i choose App Service "S2: 2 Cores(s), 3.5 GB RAM, 50 GB Storage, $0.200", is 50GB disk space include OS or space allocated to file which we upload?

**Sixth**: Some of our application are used to send push notification to iOS & Android device i am not sure if they will work in Azure environment as they need certain ports to be open and also some sort of certificate to be installed on the server.

I have asked too many question as i didn't had clarity from MS chat as they just passed links which can be confusing at time, i hope i get clarity here

Comment: May I suggest you split this question in 6 separate questions. IMHO, it would be really cumbersome for someone to answer all of them in a single go.

Comment: @GauravMantri, I know it is too many question, i did this so people will get the whole picture. i dont mind if user reply to specific part of question based on there expertise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Q: First, my big concerns are session state, i want to migrate to Azure without making any changes to code except changes to web.config is this possible?**

If one of your concerns is code refactoring, then the model you should chose is Infrastructure-As-A-Service. In this model, there is no need to change in code because the infrastructure on Azure can be similar to the on-premises in which you provision virtual machines to run Windows Server, SQL Server and IIS. Software versions are all of your choice with no limitation. As long as the software version is still supported in Microsoft product lifecycle when procuring new software license.

If you'd love to modernize your web application, Azure App Service can be a good chosen destination. Azure App Service can run code compiled against .NET 4.0 framewor. **InProc session** state is not guaranteed in Azure App Service so you need to look into an alternative if using Azure App Service, for example Azure [Redis Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-aspnet-session-state-provider).

**Q: Second we use MS SQL SERVER 2012 as database and on azure we have to use Azure SQL Database which i believe is not same as MS SQL SERVER, Can i use Azure SQL Database or i should still to MS SQL SERVER as i have application running on this and migrating to Azure database may create problems?**

Without impact analysis and how complex your data model is, it's hard to say whether Azure SQL Database is compatible with your database. Fortunately, Microsoft provides a tool named Data Migration Assistant (DAM) which assists you to perform database compatibility analysis for Azure SQL Database. This link gives you more details on DAM (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-cloud-migrate). Moving from SQL Server to Azure SQL Database would gain more benefits in high availability, disaster recovery and scalability. Administration effort with server management, OS patching is significantly reduced. With SQL Server in Azure VM, the migration cost is much better as you only need to shift and lift (provision VM, perform database detach/attach or other backup/restore methods).

**Q: Third, let us say i choose web+Mobile--> App Service Standard Package (which comes with upto 10 instance) what are these instance? and will individual session always connect to same instance?**

No, session would not be maintained in guaranteed mode. When you chose Azure App Service, your web application will be run on virtualized servers running Windows Server and IIS. The term "Instance" is server instance. Azure App Service helps you handle scaling by allocating compute resource across multiple instance to make sure your application does not get crashed with inadequate memory and resource. The default at the first time you provision your web app is 1, but the number of instance is configurable.

**Q: Forth: I have about 20 database one of them is about 6GB & other database are about 200MB-700MB which service should i use for database in case i use Azure SQL Database
Single Database or Elastic?
Can i create multiple database under elastic mode?
Let us say if i choose "100 eDTUs: 10 GB included storage per pool, 200 DBs per pool, $0.20/hour" will i have total of 10GB space for all database in elastic pool and what is per pool and how many pools will i get in this option.
or MS SQL SERVER on Virtual Machine is better option as i can run SQL Server based session**

Choosing Single Database or Elastic depends on performance and peak load of your database. Single database is used for independently database, when you can specify the DTU (Data Transaction Unit) for predictable performance. While Elastic Pool is best for managing set of databases in a pool. Elastic Pool is a choice for unpredictable performance and usage.

In your case, I'd recommend to use Elastic Pool to rescue performance. Elastic Pool allows you to set eDTU for your pool no matter how much of DTU a specific database in a pool needs. Elastic Pool monitors and perform performance analysis in depth to give you an insight and overall picture of each database performance.

When it comes to pool, you should not worry about how much storage you are given to each database. You don't also have to worry about the number of databases you can store in a pool. Saying you have total 20 databases, you need only one pool. 
The eDTU you need can be calculated via this website http://dtucalculator.azurewebsites.net/. Just run one of the given scripts in the website on your SQL Server (where your on-premises databases are running) to capture performance metrics, then upload Excel file to the website. It will gives you a number. For example, the result says that total 20 databases need totally 100 eDTU. Then you just create an Elastic pool and adjust 100 eDTU for the pool. However, if using Elastic Pool Basic, you are only given 10 GB per pool which is not enough for 120 GB (20 * 6 GB), then you need Elastic Pool Standard for 100 eDTU to achieve 750 GB maximum. Note that you can choose Basic plan of 1,200 eDTU to achieve 156 GB maximum. However, this way is never recommended because storage space is much cheaper than eDTU.

In a nutshell, with your draft info above, I'd recommend to chose Standard plan of Elastic Pool with 100 eDTU. You can increase number of eDTU if it does not satisfy the performance of totally 20 databases. No database downtime is needed when adjusting eDTU number.

Creating only 1 pool is not really my recommendation. It depends on your database workload. For example, in 20 databases, there are 5 databases that are heavy workload for an ERP or business-critical systems while the rest are just normal databases. In this case, you'd need two Elastic pools. One pool with high number of eDTU is set, and another pool has low number of eDTU.

**Q: Fifth: Disk Space, let us say i choose App Service "S2: 2 Cores(s), 3.5 GB RAM, 50 GB Storage, $0.200", is 50GB disk space include OS or space allocated to file which we upload?**

When it comes to Azure App Service, OS is not counted in. 50 GB storage space is given directly to your application's space (to store image, compiled DLL, video, library..)

**Q: Sixth: Some of our application are used to send push notification to iOS & Android device i am not sure if they will work in Azure environment as they need certain ports to be open and also some sort of certificate to be installed on the server.**

Azure Notification Hubs can help you achieve push notification. Azure Notification Hub allows you to use certificate of each kind of platform (e.g iOS to manage devices. This is a sample reference if you are familiar with iOS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-ios-apple-push-notification-apns-get-started. Azure Notification Hub also supports token-based for APNS if you need.

For each case, please give more details (e.g. your mobile scenario) , and specific questions if possible so I and people here can elaborate more.

Comment: Thanks for such a details answer, Can you tell me how reliable is `ARR Affinity` for session state for low profile website for busy website we can choose `Redis cache` Regarding migration i already tested some of the old website database, usually it gives some redundancy issue with `asp.net memberships` table

Comment: example for SQL SERVER TO SQL SERVER `"Name": "dbo.aspnet_Membership_FindUsersByEmail",
              "ObjectType": "Procedure",
              "ImpactDetail": "Object [dbo].[aspnet_Membership_FindUsersByEmail] uses the old style join syntax which can have poor performance at database compatibility level 90 and higher. For more details, please see: Line 32, Column 13.\n Object [dbo].[aspnet_Membership_FindUsersByEmail] uses the old style join syntax which can have poor performance at database compatibility level 90 and higher. For more details, please see: Line 38, Colu.....`

Comment: In terms of ARR Affinity there would not be a problem.

Comment: With Db compability, it would be better to update the join. Here is the reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240720(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: Thanks again, But it old query will work but performance will be slow.

Comment: You seem to be good at this, just one more question let us say tommorrow up upgrade to two instances with that create any problem for example will all files (images, .asps, .cs, .dll, .txt, videos etc..) be replicated to other instances.. how does store work in this case. for example i upload image using instance 1 will that image be available to second user who connected using instance 2

Comment: @Learning Your storage is actually a file server which mounts blobs and expose them as network drives to worker engine at the back-end. This worker engine will run to make sure that your application always see "local" file in network drive. Well, this would be a receipt of secret of how Azure App Service architecture runs behind the scene which I'm don't know. At least we know auto-scale is done by worker and you shouldn't worry about your file stored in app's storage.

Comment: You have left no me choice other than marking this as a answer even though i wanted to wait for more reply but you time is appreciated. you seem to know lot about Azure

Comment: Thanks, Do i need to take anything into consideration from security point of view regarding azure or it is handled by azure

Comment: Trusting Azure to protect your Azure application deployment is one of the very common misconceptions. Even Microsoft achieves many international and national-wide security compliance and certification, this does not mean you are fully protected. When it comes to Azure security, there are a lot more to talk and you HAVE TO care every of it. For example, in Azure App Service, be aware of using HTTPs with a good certificate to secure your HTTP. Or in DB, you need to look into Dynamic Data Masking, Transparent Data Encryption.

Comment: Moreover, your web app may also need Application Gateway which plays as a web application firewall to inspect incoming HTTP request. Your database needs to control inbound so you know who connect to your database connection string internally. Well, my comment here is never enough. Give me a specific question or ping me for further and comprehensive strategy.